# Calculate depth disparity map using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have trouble calculating depth from disparity map using opencv. I know that the distance in two stereo images is calculated with `z = (baseline * focal) / (disparity * p)` but I can not figure out how to calculate the disparity using the map. The code I use if the following, providing me with a disparity map of the two images.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load the left and right images in gray scale
imgLeft = cv2.imread('logga.png', 0)
imgRight = cv2.imread('logga1.png', 0)

# Initialize the stereo block matching object 
stereo = cv2.StereoBM_create(numDisparities=16, blockSize=5)

# Compute the disparity image
disparity = stereo.compute(imgLeft, imgRight)

# Normalize the image for representation
min = disparity.min()
max = disparity.max()
disparity = np.uint8(6400 * (disparity - min) / (max - min))



# Display the result
cv2.imshow('disparittet', np.hstack((imgLeft, imgRight, disparity)))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2):

For calculating the depth from disparity, OpenCV has the function [reprojectImageTo3d](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#reprojectimageto3d).

You need the disparity-to-depth matrix (Q) from stereo rectification (or you can create it as given in the link). You can learn more about the Q matrix [here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/187734/derivation-for-perspective-transformation-matrix-q/?answer=187997#post-id-187997).

After getting the Q matrix, you can simply reproject the disparity map to 3D

`depth = cv2.reprojectImageTo3D(disparity, Q)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have done the following and currently output the data into a document in which I get around 312000 lines of output.

For example I get the property x,y and z information aswell as the RGB info in each pixel.

In line 33 I get the following: -77.00000 188.0000 -121920.0000 147 166 125.

What I want is the disparity between to or a bulk of pixels that I later can add to my mathematical formula which calculates the distance. It is D = (f*b)/d where D is distance, f is focal lenght, b is baseline and d i disparity. The value of d is around 40. How do I get it?

Comment: You have used Simple Block matching here. You can try Semi-Global Block matching also to calculate disparity. Here in the numDisparities, you have set it as 16. You need to set it in multiples of 16 in OpenCV, so you need to set the number of disparity to 48. I think you might need to divide the result of disparity by 16 before calculating the depth.

Comment: I see. I have posted a new question regarding the problem and would appreciate your help if you don't mind. Thank you!