# Obtaining Q matrix from stereoRectifyUncalibrated

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to create a depth map and calculate the depth of the objects shown in the images without calibration.

I have the disparity map obtained from `StereoSGBM_create` and now I need a Q matrix so I can input them in `reprojectImageTo3D` which I learned from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58113312/calculate-depth-disparity-map-using-opencv)

One of the answers there says that the Q matrix(of size 4,4) can be obtained from stereo rectification so I ran `stereoRectifyUncalibrated` in order to obtain the Q matrix but instead I get two separate matrices of size 3,3.

How do I calculate the Q matrix if I am using cameras that are not calibrated?

Answer (score 0):

Stepping from disparity to depth requires calibration.  In fact, Q contains the intrinsic parameters of the cameras and the baseline length.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34777381)